# AFHTTPSessionManager subclass swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-2, afhttpsessionmanager

What is the correct way to create singletone subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager with custom session configuration?

```
class DefaultSessionConfiguration: NSURLSessionConfiguration {

    override init () {

        super.init()

        self.HTTPShouldSetCookies = true
        HTTPCookieStorage?.cookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy.Always
        HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [ "Content-Type": "application/json"];
    }

}

let baseUrl = "https://google.com"

class HTTPManager: AFHTTPSessionManager {


    static let _sharedAPIManager = HTTPManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: baseUrl)!, sessionConfiguration:DefaultSessionConfiguration())

    class var sharedInstance : HTTPManager {
        return _sharedAPIManager
    }

    override init(baseURL url: NSURL!, sessionConfiguration session:NSURLSessionConfiguration? ) {

        super.init(baseURL: url, sessionConfiguration: session)
        self.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer() as AFJSONResponseSerializer
        self.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer() as AFJSONRequestSerializer

    }

}
```

While trying to use this code as  `self.sessionManager = HTTPManager.sharedInstance` it is always crashed with message

> [MyApp.DefaultSessionConfiguration setHTTPShouldSetCookies:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f99f8f31b70

but MyApp.DefaultSessionConfiguration is subclass of NSURLSessionConfiguration and defenetly has this method.

So, how do we solve this problem?

Comment: BTW, you don't have to set the `Content-Type` header, because using `AFJSONRequestSerializer` will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you shouldn't be instantiating a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` directly. You should instantiate it by calling one of the following class methods: `defaultSessionConfiguration`, `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` or `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`. For example:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPShouldSetCookies = true
configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.cookieAcceptPolicy = .Always
```